# json_encode utf8

Tags: php, utf-8, json

I put some Data in my mysql DB that works fine.
But when I get the Data with json_encode I get ist back like this:

```
{"idpostdata":"49","artID":null,"timestamp":"06.11.2012 13:35","lat":"51.496911","lon":"7.4022327","cellID":null,"road":"Wittener Stra\u00dfe","suburb":"Eichlinghofen","city":"Dortmund","postdatacol":null,"state_district":"Regierungsbezirk Arnsberg","state":"North Rhine-Westphalia","country_code":"de"}
```

you see `"road":"Wittener Stra\u00dfe"` is not the correct name it must Wittener Straße

My Code:

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM postdata");

while ($ds = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
  $output[]=$ds;
echo "{uTraf:";
  print(json_encode($output));
echo  "}";
mysql_close($dz);
?>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: It's not incorrect since `\u00df` is the JSON escape sequence for the German sharp S (ß). The question is rather is the escaping really needed and if not how can it be avoided.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is wrong?

Nothing. `\uxxxx` is JSON's way of encoding UTF-8 characters.

It will look all right again when you decode the JSON using a proper JSON decoding method.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong it's part of the json_encoding to prevent faulty character conversion:

Look it up : \u00df

http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

When you `json_decode($string);` it should be fixed again

Answer (score -1):

Use addslashes when you save json data to mysql. And when you get data out, it is will be OK.